# htaccess redirect English URL to French

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a bilingual website in WordPress. I have updated the htaccess to redirect the users when they type in the French URL to redirect to the English french version but it isn't working. Can someone help me?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^french\.ca$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.french\.ca$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.english\.ca\/fr\/" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: WHat's not working? do you have other rules? what URL are you trying? does both the french and english domain point to the same server? where is your htaccess file? what does your error logs say?

Answer (score 0):

Try with that:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?french\.ca$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.english.ca/fr/ [R=301,L]
```

It's just the simplest version of the same code.
And after, try to clear cache or with other browser.